# Angular Material Mat-Card Interpolation to add html formatted string error

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have a Angular Material Mat-Card where I want need to add interpolation to add a content string to the mat-card-content.

The following works without interpolation

```
 <mat-card-content>
            <p>Guidelines.</p>
            <p>Click on the folliwng link for additional information</p>
            <a href="http://mySite/documents/guidances.docx">http://mySite/documents/guidances.docx</a>
        </mat-card-content>
```

The page with render with a working link

I the content will be coming from the webservice and no longer be a static page. Now I insert the content as the following

```
<mat-card>
                        **<mat-card-content>{{message.content}}</mat-card-content>**
                    </mat-card>
```

When the hmtl page renders, it does not do any html formatting for the string.

it looks like this

```
<p>Guidelines.</p><p>UClick on the folliwng link for additional information</p><a href="http://mySite/documents/guidances.docx">http://mySite/documents/guidances.docx</a>
```

It just paste the html code inside the amt-card.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Use like this - `<div [innerHTML]="displayString"></div>`. Interpolation does not parse html.

Answer (score 5):

you can use innerHtml:

```
<mat-card-content>
 <div [innerHTML]="message.content"></div>
</mat-card-content>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap the content in a div and display it using the `innerHtml` attribute like this:

```
<mat-card>
   <mat-card-content><div [innerHtml]="message.content"></div></mat-card-content>
</mat-card>
```

Note: You should sanitize the input (in your case `message.content`) in your controller using [DomSanitizer](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/DomSanitizer)

Eg:

```
import { DomSanitizer } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { SecurityContext } from '@angular/core';

constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer){}

...

message.content = this.sanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML, value); // `value` is the value being assigned to `message.content`
```